# iframe overlay any div with transparency in firefox

Tags: html, css, iframe

I created a custom dialog-box for my site. So, it need overlay any content to show some messages. However I have a iframe with a third part content for a webchat interaction.

If I set a opaque `background-color` for my div, works fine. It overlay the iframe content. However if I do something like: `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9)` or even `opacity: 0.9`, the iframe content overlay my div. This is only happening in firefox, chrome works fine.

I do some test like this:

```css
.dialog-box-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 5000;
}
.dialog-box-2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: White;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #000;
  z-index: 5000;
}
.chat {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-box-content">
  <div class="dialog-box-2">some-content</div>
</div>

<iframe class="chat" src="http://vircio.net/sala/mtgobycockatrice&estilo=darkorange&autoconectar=1&ocultarEntradas=1&altura=500?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">
</iframe>
```

What I get is:

[image]

This is happing only in firefox.

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: @vel, how can i create this? i am new here, isn't code snippet enough for helpers?

Comment: Go to this link https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ok, thanks @val. created: [https://jsfiddle.net/ndanilo1/wyprcex4/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/ndanilo1/wyprcex4/1/)